# Ros1_bridge can't mapping my msgs..... HELP

Tags: ros, ros2, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ros1_bridge by apt install ros-dashing-ros1_birdge.
and refered to https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/doc/index.rst.

i make 'my_mapping_rules.yaml'

```
<my_mapping_rules.yaml>
-
  ros1_package_name: 'tut_msgs'
  ros1_message_name: 'Num'
  ros2_package_name: 'tut_msgs'
  ros2_message_name: 'Num'

  fields_1_to_2:
    data: 'data' 




#/home/freesun/ros2_ws/src/tut_msgs/msg/Num.msg                  ros2_workspace
#/home/freesun/catkin_ws/src/tut_msgs/msg/Num.msg                ros1_workspace
```

and placed in /home/freesun/ros2_ws/src/tut_msgs
Finally i modifed msg's CMakeList.txt and package.xml.

But it doesn't working. CANT MAPPING MY MESSAGES!!!!!!!

what's the problem???

HELP ME PLZ..... OTL

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347087/ros1_bridge-can%27t-mapping-my-msgs.....-help/) by [Freesun](https://answers.ros.org/users/52674/freesun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> installed Ros1_bridge by apt install ros-dashing-ros1_birdge

This is the reason. The bridge provided in `ros-dashing-ros1-bridge` has no knowledge of *your* messages. You need to build a custom bridge from source.

If you follow the steps of the document you link to https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/doc/index.rst#how-does-the-bridge-know-about-custom-interfaces it will guide you through how to setup workspaces, build your messages and how to build a bridge capable of bridging your messages

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Freesun](https://answers.ros.org/users/52674/freesun/) on 2020-03-19**:
oh! i got it! i'll do that!! thx  :)

**Comment by [Freesun](https://answers.ros.org/users/52674/freesun/) on 2020-03-19**:
umm.... i faced another problem! when i run all nodes.
ros1_bridge suddenly shut down.
here is error message :

```
   $ ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge 
created 2to1 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ROS 2 type 'rcl_interfaces/msg/Log' and ROS 1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'
created 1to2 bridge for topic '/my_topic' with ROS 1 type 'tut_msgs/Num' and ROS 2 type 'tut_msgs/msg/Num'
[INFO] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 1 tut_msgs/Num to ROS 2 tut_msgs/msg/Num (showing msg only once per type)
realloc(): invalid pointer
```

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-03-19**:
this is unfortunate

Are you using CycloneDDS by any chance ?
Did you try looking for a similar issue on the ros1_bridge repository ? This looks pretty similar to your issue https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/244

**Comment by [Freesun](https://answers.ros.org/users/52674/freesun/) on 2020-03-19**:
okay... i'll search more issues!  thank u  ;)

**Comment by [Freesun](https://answers.ros.org/users/52674/freesun/) on 2020-03-20**:
Hello!! I solved it when i install cyclone dds!!

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-03-20**:
glad you can now bridge your messages.
As your problem is solved, could you please close the question or,  if it answered your original question, accept the proposed answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.
This will allow to remove your question from the unanswered list